# Bounds on how far away most leaves are from the average height of a binary tree

Tags: graph-theory, inequality, trees

I'm wondering if anyone can help me prove (or disprove) this statement?

> Say there is a rooted full binary tree (each non-leaf node has exactly two children) with a height of $h$, an average height of $t$, and $l$ leaves. Then for $k \geq 1$ there are at most $\frac{l}{k}$ leaves above a height of $kt$.

I think the statement is correct and basically I've been trying to assume the contrary and come up with a contradiction using the average height -- but no success.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the word 'above' in your statement?  It has two distinct plausible interpretations: 'whose height is larger than the height $kt$', or 'which are visually/metaphorically 'above' the height $kt$, in the sense that their height is less than that'...

Comment: Sorry yes that is rather confusing. I meant the first interpretation. A leaf of height 3 is "above" a node of height 2.

Comment: Further clarification, the average height of a tree is the sum of the height of the leaves, divided by the number of leaves. The height of non-leaf nodes is not counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the terminology of height of a node may be confusing here, so let's make it clear first how I interpret it:

*The height of the root is 0; if a node has height $j$, its children has height $j+1$. Being **above** means having larger height, i.e. further from the root. Thus, one thinks of the root at the bottom and the leaves at the top, not the other way around.*

If the tree has $m_j$ leaves at height $j$, where $h$ is the maximal height (i.e. $\sum_j$ means $\sum_{j=0}^h$), then $l=\sum_j m_j$ and $l\cdot t=\sum_j jm_j$. Let me rephrase the problem slightly: for any $a>0$ (where $a=kt$ in the original), there are at most $lt/a$ leaves with height $j\ge a$. This follows from
$$\sum_{j\ge a} m_h
 =\frac{1}{a}\sum_{j\ge a} am_j
 \le\frac{1}{a}\sum_{j=0}^h jm_j
 =\frac{lt}{a}.
$$

The requirement that $k\ge1$ (i.e. $a\ge t$) is not required, only that $a>0$. Of course, the only interesting values of $a$ are integers.

It may also be noted that the result doesn't make use of the fact these are leaves on a binary tree: they are just leaves with values (in this case height) attached to them.

Answer (score 2):

The tree shown below is a counterexample to the current version of the conjecture.

```
                    o  
                   / \  
                  o   o  
                 / \  
                o   o
```

Here $h=2$, $t=\frac15(1\cdot0+2\cdot1+2\cdot2)=\frac65$, and $\ell=3$. Take $k=\frac85$; then $\frac{\ell}k=\frac{15}8<2$, but there are $2$ leaves of height $2>\frac{48}{25}=\frac65\cdot\frac85=kt$.

Comment: It's not clear in what sense the poster means the phrase 'above' - it could as easily mean 'whose height is less than $kt$', esp. since they don't use the word 'height' before they use above.

Comment: @Steven: I suppose that it’s barely possible, but it would be completely unidiomatic.

Comment: It depends on the idiom one's used to, I suppose.  I've often seen a node's ancestors referred to as the nodes above it...

Comment: @Steven: But here we’re talking about numbers, not nodes. Besides, $\ell/k$ decreases as $k$ increases, as does the number of nodes of height greater than $kt$.

Comment: True - I'd missed the sense of the dependency on $k$, which makes your interpretation much more likely.

Comment: (Now that the OP has clarified, incidentally, the average height $t$ of your tree by his rules is 5/3, so this example no longer works.)